# Не работает else в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
function Register(player, login, password) {
    SQL.Query(`SELECT login FROM user_info WHERE login='${login}'`, function(result) {
        if (result[0].login == login) {
            player.outputChatBox(`[Ошибка] Данный логин уже занят!`)
        } else { // не работает else. if при этом работает отлично
            player.outputChatBox(`Вы успешно зарегистрировались! Используйте: '/login [логин] [пароль]' для входа.`)
        }
    })
}
```

Не работает else. Но при этом if работает отлично. Пробовал через return, switch - тоже не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вместо outputChatBox я пробовал console.log - результат тот же. Скорее тут проблема в самом условии if.

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Выводится сообщение "Извините, код не работает"? Программа падает? Выключается компьютер? Что?

Answer (score 0):

Скобки в строке. Экранировать их нужно вроде. Попробуйте в else в outputChatBox строку без скобок внутри. Напрмиер ('works!!'). Если заработает - то проблема 100% в скобках.

Comment: Всё равно не работает.